# Bulgarian citizen can travel to Canada without visa

Tags: canada, europe, bulgarian-citizens

Travel to Canada as Bulgarian ?

Answer (score 2):

Like all EU citizens, Bulgarian citizens can usually travel to Canada with just an ETA (an electronic travel authorisation, which you apply for online).

However, at the current time, only Canadian citizens and permanent residents and a few other exceptions can enter Canada due to COVID-19 restrictions.

Fully vaccinated foreigners will normally be able to enter Canada again from September 7, but this can of course still change.

Comment: While this answer was correct when it was written, it [no longer is](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta.html).  US citizens and permanent residents who are fully vaccinated may enter Canada for discretionary travel effective today.  Fully-vaccinated people from the rest of the world will be able to do the same (it is anticipated) as of September 7.